# Unable to press down arrow key in Mink Behat

Tags: php, selenium, behat, mink

I am trying to click on a button and if I press down arrow key on that button then the list of values appears, but my automation script only clicking the button, not able to trigger down arrow key. we have Behat mink PHP based framework.
Screenshot of the split button
    
    
    Month

Comment: Try using a method for key press or use a javascript script to trigger an event on that element.

Comment: I have used mink predefined method from feature context press the key(KeyDown and KeyPress) still it is not recognizing the button.